# Sql query taking values from the column in the excelsheet using VBA(macro)

Tags: sql, vba

I need to use sql query using VBA. My input values for the query is from the Column in the excel sheet.I need to take all the values present in the column and it should be passed as input to the query to sqlserver. But i could'nt get the answer. I am getting type mismatch as error. could any one help me out. Thanks in advance

for example in J column contains J1=25, j2=26, ....so on

```
stSQL = "SELECT * FROM prod..status where state in"      

stSQL = stSQL & wsSheet.Range("J:J").Value
```

My full code is below

```
Sub Add_Results_Of_ADO_Recordset()

     'This was set up using Microsoft ActiveX Data Components version 2.8

    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim stSQL As Variant
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rnStart As Range


    Const stADO As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
    "Persist Security Info=False;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=prod;" & _
    "Data Source=777777777V009D\YTR_MAIN4_T"
     'where BI is SQL Database & AURDWDEV01 is SQL Server

    Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("sheet1")

    With wsSheet
        Set rnStart = .Range("A2")
    End With


     ' My SQL Query       



    stSQL = "SELECT  * FROM prod..status where state in"



stSQL = stSQL + wsSheet.Range("J:J").Value


    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

    With cnt
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open stADO
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
    End With

     'Here we add the Recordset to the sheet from A1
    rnStart.CopyFromRecordset rst

     'Cleaning up.
    rst.Close
    cnt.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to

```
stSQL = stSQL + " ('" + Replace(wsSheet.range("J:J").Value, "'", "") + ")"
```

but sql IN statement is usually used like this

```
state IN (25,26,28)
```

But if you are only using one integer value you might want to go this way.

```
stSQL = "SELECT * FROM prod..status where state = "
stSQL = Val(wsSheet.range("J:J").Value)
```

There is though one thing that is dangerous in using a in statement.
If your In part of the statement is very long, it will become slow and then with even larger in statements crash altogeather.

The solution for that kind of situation is creating a temp table with the in values and do where in (temp table) or a inner join based on the temp table

Comment: @ Archlight I tried using your code. But it is givng the same error. The problem is the row count will be more than 1000. It is throwing error when i try to concatenate the 1000 values to a single string.

Comment: so your problem is .. where state in (1,2,3... one thousand values ??)

or is it when you are trying to work with the results from the sql server?

Comment: when i try to make more than 80k rows , i am getting error.  But i could get the values right for 30k records.

Comment: If the IN part of the sql is not very long it has nothing to do with the sql part but more with how you are consuming it. Add the CopyFromRecordset code and we can look at that. Make sure you are using forward only, read only cursor/rst and what version of excel you are using because there are max nr of rows in excel sheet

Comment: I am using Excel 2007 version. Yes i am using read only resultset

Answer (score 0):

There is no space after your "in" in your stSQL variable. So if your cell contains the value "TEST", stSQL will be

```
SELECT * FROM prod..status where state inTEST
```

Answer (score 0):

I used for loop and mid command to convert the values in the column to a single variable. Below is the code i used to perform the function which i required

```
' Getting the last row
With wsSheet
lastrow1 = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

' Appending the values to a single variable

For i = 1 To lastrow
  s1 = s1 & "'" & Val(wsSheet.Cells(i, 10)) & "'" & ","
Next



' Variable which could be used in  IN command    

    If lastrow > 0 Then
        s1 = Mid(s1, 1, Len(s1) - 1)
        s1 = "(" & s1 & ")"
    Else
         Exit Sub
    End If
```