# Too many characters in Excel SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to find all `Names` for the `Ticket` number by Excel SQL Query. The problem is that I have above 10,000 numbers and SQL does not allow you to type as many characters. How could I make this possible?

```
    SELECT 
    OZATI_Ticket.Name, 
    OZATI_Ticlet.Number
    FROM 
    OZATI_Ticket
    WHERE 
    (OZATI_Ticket.Number='1234' Or 
    OZATI_Ticket.Number='4321' Or 
    OZATI_Ticket.Number='6662' Or
/*next 9997 ticket numbers*/)
    ORDER BY 
    OZATI_Ticket.Name
```

Comment: place the 1000 numbers into a separate table and do a left join.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman i.e. a temp table more than likely as suggested here in the last paragraph: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19788459/5224021

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enter that much information, the best would be to create a table listing all the tickets you want. Is it's not a possibility, you can do it like that:

```
WHERE OZATI_Ticket.Number IN = ('1234','4321','6662')
```

I hope that you will give you enough characters in that way. There is a way to get the list of ids

```
Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim str As String
currentRow = 1
Do While (sheets("data").Range("A" & currentRow).Value <> "")
    str = str & ",'" & sheets("data").Range("A" & currentRow).Value & "'"
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Loop
str = Mid(str, 2)
```

Comment: I try put this WHERE OZATI_Ticket.Number IN (SELECT * FROM [data!A1:A1000]) but I see error <identifier>

Comment: You will not be able to join in a list directly in Excel, if you want to do it like that, you need to output the result in a Sting before. I'll add an exemple in the answer.